# Per-App VPN for iOS7, Not connected to VPN on App Launch

Tags: ios, vpn, mdm

I am not able to get the VPN turned on automatically when the app targeted for a per-app vpn connection is launched.

I have the following flags set in my VPN payload:

```
<key>VPNUUID</key>
<string>7EF39436-BE7B-DBFE-53E8-2FEB0ECD7D56.vpn</string>
<key>OnDemandMatchAppEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

and below is the Managed Setting command published to set the VPN for the target app:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestType</key>
        <string>Settings</string>
        <key>Settings</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Item</key>
                <string>ApplicationAttributes</string>
                <key>Identifier</key>
                <string>com.vertex.iStocks</string>
                <key>Attributes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>VPNUUID</key>
                    <string>7EF39436-BE7B-DBFE-53E8-2FEB0ECD7D56.vpn</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>4174923E-414D-8AB1-B5DD-2246647D895B</string>
</dict>
```

On installing the configuration profile, I get the below error:

```
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd starting...
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Looking for managed app states to clean up
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Push token received.
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Received push notification.
Jul 11 17:02:59 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Polling MDM server https://dc27.mymdm.net/dccontrollerc/processresponse for next command.
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Attempting to perform MDM request: InstallProfile
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Loaded VPNUtilities.framework
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Checking for MDM installation...
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: ...finished checking for MDM installation.
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Loaded VPNUtilities.framework
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Beginning profile installation...
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Profile “com.apple.mgmt.mymdm.mdmF3A9BD12-2E5E-A2D4-49D2-81F70C7571F9” is replacing an existing profile having the same identifier.
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:3)
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod() => (0,0,0)
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod() => (0,0,0)
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: get_longlongvalue_for_key: failed to get GracePeriod
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: get_longlongvalue_for_key: failed to get MaxLifetime
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod(-1,5,-1)
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod: from AKS 0
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad keybagd[46] <Error>: 0x295000 __update_system_keybag_block_invoke: Updating System Keybag
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad keybagd[46] <Error>: 0x295000 KBUpdateSystemKeyBag: Got opaqueStuff from ondisk keybag
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad configd[58] <Notice>: SCNC: stop, triggered by (58) configd, type IPSec, reason Service Disposed
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad configd[58] <Notice>: network changed.
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad keybagd[46] <Error>: 0x295000 KBUpdateSystemKeyBag: Saved new keybag with result 2707224
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad securityd[79] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad securityd[79] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Jul 11 17:03:01 Manmays-iPad securityd[79] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Profile “com.apple.mgmt.mymdm.mdmF3A9BD12-2E5E-A2D4-49D2-81F70C7571F9” installed.
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad corecaptured[212] <Warning>: CCXPCService::setStreamEventHandler Woken up by notifyd.
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad configd[58] <Notice>: network changed.
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad corecaptured[212] <Warning>: CCProfileMonitor::profileCallback Entered token:4
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad profiled[218] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x14562af0)
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad corecaptured[212] <Warning>: CCLogTap::profileRemoved
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad corecaptured[212] <Warning>: CCDataFile::profileRemoved
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad corecaptured[212] <Warning>: CCLogTap::profileRemoved
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Command Status: Acknowledged
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad afcd[90] <Error>: Checking for changed log settings
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad afcd[90] <Error>: valid 0 value 0
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad afcd[90] <Error>: Verbose logging disabled
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Polling MDM server https://dc27.mymdm.net/dccontrollerc/processresponse for next command.
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[221] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: mc_mobile_tunnel starting.
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad awdd[220] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Attempting to perform MDM request: Settings
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Handling request type: Settings
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Command Status: Acknowledged
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Command Status: Acknowledged
Jul 11 17:03:02 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Polling MDM server https://dc27.mymdm.net/dccontrollerc/processresponse for next command.
Jul 11 17:03:03 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jul 11 17:03:03 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Attempting to perform MDM request: ProfileList
Jul 11 17:03:03 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Handling request type: ProfileList
Jul 11 17:03:03 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Command Status: Acknowledged
```

And below is the log when I launch the app:

```
Jul 11 17:04:19 Manmays-iPad mdmd[217] <Error>: TASK-ASSERT: cfurlcache - ProcessCacheTask - FAILED to get task-assertion, going commando with 16 items to process.
Jul 11 17:04:20 Manmays-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[223] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/D0C06305-AA03-4A32-A8D2-51C55722814C (sandbox)
Jul 11 17:04:20 Manmays-iPad backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'iStocks' access to protected services is denied.
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Warning>: Enabling Crittercism v4.3.1...
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Error>: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Error>: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Warning>: Crittercism - Using cached delegate list.
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Warning>: Crittercism successfully initialized.
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Warning>: Crittercism network monitoring: enabled
Jul 11 17:04:21 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Warning>: Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
Jul 11 17:04:22 Manmays-iPad backboardd[28] <Warning>: |GuidedAccess|warning| SpringBoard server could not disconnect from frontmost app message service gracefully: (null)
Jul 11 17:04:23 Manmays-iPad iStocks[223] <Warning>: Crittercism - net data collection enabled, frequency: 10s
```

**I am trying per-app vpn on a non-supervised device iOS7.1.2, I guess that is correct!!**

Please help

Comment: please help me with some valuable suggestions!!!